# Change beamer notes list type for in-frame notes

Tags: beamer, itemize, notes

When you use the `\note{}` command within a frame, the notes are appended to a notes frame after the current frame. If you use `\note[item]{}`, each note is an item in an enumerated list. Can this be changed to an itemized list with the same in-frame note command, i.e. so that `\note[item]{}` appends an itemized list rather than enumerated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can redefine the internal `\beamer@setupnote` command to use an `itemize` environment instead of the default `enumerate` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@setupnote{%
  \gdef\beamer@notesactions{%
    \beamer@outsideframenote{%
      \beamer@atbeginnote%
      \beamer@notes%
      \ifx\beamer@noteitems\@empty\else
      \begin{itemize}\itemsep=0pt\parskip=0pt%
        \beamer@noteitems%
      \end{itemize}%
      \fi%
      \beamer@atendnote%
    }%
    \gdef\beamer@notesactions{}%
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test
\note[item]{First note.}
\note[item]{Second note.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here's the image of the note page obtained:

[image]

Of course, for notes build using `\note` *outside* frames you don't need any redefinition, since you can use the `itemize` option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}
\note[itemize]
{
\item{First note.}
\item{Second note.}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about \note{
\begin{itemize}
\item First note.
\item Second note.
\end{itemize}
}

Answer (score 9):

You can use `\AtBeginNote` to redefine `enumerate` as `itemize` in the frames displaying notes. Simply add

```
\AtBeginNote{%
    \let\enumerate\itemize%
    \let\endenumerate\enditemize%
}
```

to your preamble (if you already have an `\AtBeginNote` definition there, you need to merge the two commands).

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness sake:
If you want to change an individual items icon, you give the icon-optarg as first element inside the curly braces.

```
\note<2->[item]{[step 2] this note is preceeded by 'step 2'}
\note<3->[item]{[\textbullet] this looks like itemize}
\note<4->[item]{[\theenumi] this repeats the last items number}
\note<5->[item]{without opt-arg. This IS enumerate.}
\note<5->[item]{[\stepcounter{enumi}\theenumi.] this acts like enumerate.}
\note<5->[item]{[\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi.] same, but for hyperref}
```

Note that only the last three versions advance the item-counter. Thus if you add notes with other icon-options, it will pick up the numbering where it was interrupted before.

Also note, that while the overlay option describes on which slide the note exists, the ordering is based on the actual order. Thus if you use the following, you'll *insert* a note in between notes on previous slides.

```
\note<2->[item]{first note-item on second slide}
\note<3->[item]{on third slide, this will pop up between}
\note<2->[item]{second note-item on second slide}
\note<3->{notes without the item-optarg are written continuously above the list}
```