# Notes in Beamer document class: lonely \item

Tags: beamer, enumerate, itemize, notes

I am having a problem with preparing my Bachelor Thesis presentation. Whenever I try to add notes with the `enumerate` or `itemize`option the compiler returns the following error error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>
> Type  H   for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.14   \end{frame}

Here's an MWE:

```
\title{Test Title}
\author{Test Author}

\documentclass[8pt, notes]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test Frame}

    \lipsum*[10]

    \note[itemize]{\item Test note 1 \item Test note 2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`itemize` is not a valid option for the `\note{}` command. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28966/change-beamer-notes-list-type-for-in-frame-notes) question and answers on how to get itemize bullets inside `\note{}`. Alternatively, use  `[item]` as an option to get an enumerated list.

Comment: I have the same problem with `\note[enumerate]`